# How to "Go to Symbol' in current open file in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, sublimetext

In Sublime Text there is shorcut for Go To symbol in current file: *Ctrl + R*

In PyCharm there is only global Go to Symbol, for the whole project *Ctrl+Alt+Shift + N*

How can I search for symbol only in current open file in PyCharm?

Comment: Try `Navigate | File Structure...` (should be `Ctrl+F12`)

Comment: @LazyOne I will copy this as an answer, because this IS the correct answer to the question. If you want to post it as an answer then I will remove mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Navigate | File Structure... presents a list of symbols for the current file, and can be filtered by typing.

The shortcut by default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

NOTE: credit should go to @LazyOne. This is merely a copy of his comment, which actually answers the question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html) help topic by PyCharm Official Help:

```
On the main menu, point to Navigate, and then choose Class, File, or Symbol respectively, or use the following shortcuts:
Class: ⌘O
File (directory): ⇧⌘O
Symbol: ⌥⌘O
```